# Get position of the correct indentation level for a Sublime Text 3 plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to create a Sublime Text 3 plugin which should insert text at the selected line(s) at the correct indentation level.

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

This is what I have thus far:

```py
class HelloWorldCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for pos in self.view.sel():
            line = self.view.line(pos)
            # Get Correct indentation level and pass in instead of line.begin()
            self.view.insert(edit, line.begin(), "Hello world;\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually just do it like this and get the indent with python:

```py
class HelloWorldCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for sel in self.view.sel():
            line = self.view.line(sel)
            line_str = self.view.substr(line)
            indent = len(line_str) - len(line_str.lstrip())
            bol = line.begin() + indent
            self.view.insert(edit, bol, "Hello world;\n")
```

If you want to keep the indentation you can change the last line to:

```py
self.view.insert(edit, bol, "Hello world;\n" + line_str[:indent])
```